# Wrong Google Play statistics in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-play

I have very big difference in statistics numbers.
I've placed bit.ly links on banners to the Google Play game page and they show that we get about 2100 visits and in the same time in Google Analytics (Google Play - Sources) it shows that we get about 30 visits on our Google Play page. Have anyone faced with such problem? How can it be fixed?